# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_acl'

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

Im trying to make a file public inside a bucket but Im having this error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_acl'

Do you see something wrong in the code?

```
def makeFilePublic(bucketName):
    s3 = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-1') 
    bucket = s3.get_bucket(bucketName)
    key = bucket.lookup('uploadedfiles/part-00000')
    key.set_acl('public-read')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that could happen is if the call to `bucket.lookup` fails to find the specified object in this bucket.  In that case, it will return a None.  You have to check for that before proceeding with the call to `set_acl`.